# Javascript image box for products

Tags: php, javascript, css, web-applications

I am looking for an "image display" script similar to the samples shown below. On hover the small images, the larger image changes (similar to Amazon.com, eBay and many other e-commerce websites).

Is there any library/code available to do this?

**Example 1**

[image: Example 1]
`---------------------------------------------------------`

**Example 2**

[image]

Comment: is this css, php or javascript question? If everything together then there are millions of galleries out there. if its the question about "how to make image appear in large box in hover" then simpliest thing is `document.getElementById('largeImage').src=this.src;`. Please be more specific

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a small example of when hovering a smaller image it will change the bigger image

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.smallImage').hover(function() {
            $('.bigImage').attr('src',this.src);
        });
    });
    </script>
    <style>
        .bigImage {
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            display: block;
        }
        .smallImage {
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
            display: inline;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="imagesDiv">
        <img class="bigImage" src="Blue hills.jpg"></img>
        <img class="smallImage" src="Blue hills.jpg"></img>
        <img class="smallImage" src="Sunset.jpg"></img>
        <img class="smallImage" src="Water lilies.jpg"></img>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```